# React Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm new to react and i'm currently experiencing this issue. I use react-router-dom for routing in my React application and when i run my code i get this error message:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

I've tried different suggestions from here but none seems to fix the problem.

For a better understanding, what led to this issue was trying to fix my react app because my Topbar & Sidebar components kept appearing below my landing-page & login page which wasn't ideal. so i came up with this fix:

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UserProfile from "./pages/userProfile/UserProfile";
import UserList from "./pages/userList/UserList";
import User from "./pages/user/User";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Landingpage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Appp />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Appp() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/userProfile">
            <UserProfile />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/project">
            <Project />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/editProject">
            <EditProject />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/testProject">
            <TestProject />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/program">
            <Program />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <UserList />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user/:userId">
            <User />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/newUser">
            <NewUser />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/products">
            <ProductList />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/product/:productId">
            <Product />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/newproduct">
            <NewProduct />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/curiMaps">
            <CuriMaps />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/newMap">
            <NewMap />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/board">
            <Board />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But after doing this, I get:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

Can anyone help?

here is a list of my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@asseinfo/react-kanban": "^2.2.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "hero-slider": "^3.1.0",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-bootstrap-carousel": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dashboard": "github:Adecodess/react-dashboard",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-slideshow-image": "^4.2.1",
    "recharts": "^2.1.4",
    "rodal": "^2.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "zustand": "^4.3.6"
```

I am hoping its a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

> From version number 6 of React Router Dom `Switch` component has been replaced by `Routes` component. Try using `Routes` instead of `Switch`

I never used more than one `Switch/Routes` component inside the `Router` component. As I can see, there are two possible errors.

1. `Toolbar` or `Sidebar` are components at wrong place.
2. Error is in some of component in `Switch` component of `Appp` component.

Try removing `Toolbar` and `Sidebar` component and see what is happening. If there is no error than that's option 1. , else it is option 2.

> If it is option 2. try putting `Router` component around `Switch/Routes` component in `Appp` component. If that doesn't work try removing `Switch` component from `Appp` component
> If it is option 1. I am not sure what is the error than, let me know if it is option number 1.

Comment: Okay, so when i remove Topbar and Side bar, I get this Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Comment: Have you tried to remove `Switch` from `Appp` component. If that doesn't help try adding `Router` component around `Switch`. If neither option helps send me errors from both options.